# Does Pushing Need To Be Adjacent?

Tags: gloomhaven

It's not specified if, when pushing, does the monster *need* to be adjacent? Some cards say specifically adjacent some don't, so the ones that don't does that mean infinite range?

Sources with answers please!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adjacency is **not** required for every Push. It depends on the card.

Push is an effect that is either attached to an attack (which can be ranged or melee) or is a part of another non-attack effect. Adjacency is only needed for melee attacks or for special abilities that explicitly state the requirement or imply it with a range of 1.

From Page 22 of the rules:

> Attack abilities will often have effects that increase their power. If
>   an attack effect is listed on an ability card after an attack, **the
>   target (or targets) of the attack is subject to the additional effect**
>   as well, after damage from the attack is resolved. Attack effects are
>   applied regardless of whether the corresponding attack does damage.
>   **Some character actions can also apply these effects without an attack,
>   and in such cases the target of the effect is written on the ability
>   card**.

The phrasing of the Push mechanic, which is considered an attack ability, is range agnostic.

> PUSH X – The target is forced to move X hexes in a direction specified
>   by the attacker, but each hex moved must place the target farther away
>   from the attacker than it was previously. If there are no viable hexes
>   into which to push the target, the push ends.

For an example of a ranged Push card, see the Cragheart's Crater card.